# How to use HTML param in Actionscript 2

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-2

The main thing in this i have written a code for swf and also the html and i need to pass the 2 parameters from html to swf i am passing clicktag param and other parameter. i know how to access the clicktag param in action script but i am getting confused to use the another parameter passed with that. i am accessing clicktag as _root.clickTAG so i can easily access it but when i wanted to use another param in the same way nothing is happening . can you anyone please help me regarding this. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in two variables using *FlashVars*. At it's simplest you can just use

```
<PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="clickTAG=http://www.domain.com&secondParam=12345">
```

(though it is worth looking at swfObject to embed the swf). Then in Flash (AS2) you can access the vars directly, eg

```
on (release) {
getURL(clickTAG + "&mySecondVarIs" + secondParam, "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside a movie clip we have to address to root like _root.clickTAG otherwise it does not work.