# flash need to have dynamic path for XML with Html Parameter

Tags: xml, flash, dynamic, path, actionscript-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use HTML param in Actionscript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365655/how-to-use-html-param-in-actionscript-2)

I have this flash mp3 player , and it read data from an XML file named "playlist.xml"
the code is :

```
if (xml == undefined && mp3 == undefined)
{
    xml = "playlist.xml";
```

now I want this Path for my xml file to be dynamic and be in the HTML doc. so I can change it with php. can you please guide me how should I change my code to read the XML path from a parameter in HTML codes ?
p.s. My Flash file is in Actionscript 2.0

Comment: -1 for not googling the answer first. There are many posts 5+ years old with the answer to your question, including this one on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365655/how-to-use-html-param-in-actionscript-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HTML:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="#" height="#" id="XXXXX" align="middle">

<param name="flashVars" value="myXML=playlist.xml" />
<param name="movie" value="URL" /><param name="menu" value="false" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="scale" value="noscale" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><embed src="URL" menu="false" quality="high" scale="noscale" bgcolor="#000000" width="200" height="200" name="XXXXX" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashVars = "myXML=playlist.xml";/>
</object>
```

if Flash:

```
if (_root.myXML)
{
   xml = _root.myXML;
}
else{
    xml = "playlist.xml";
 }
```

Comment: where should I add that HTML code ?

Comment: @FarzadHabibi see updated anwser

Comment: Thnks man , I get it working .